# C# to display date and time from the Excel File's name

Tags: c#, console-application

Given a certain date and time, I need to export the excel file name into excel, eg File_1_20170428101607 (this is the file name) to 28/04/2017 10:16 (I want this to be in the excel). I need it because I'm doing a converter tool. So I need the date and time from the file's name to be exported to another excel file.

How can I achieve this by using C# Console App?

Comment: We're not a code writing service. Please post your code that you've written to do this and we can help you fix it.

Comment: I would try to extract the datetime part with regex (\d{14}$), convert to DateTime with Time.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", ), then format the DateTime with ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

Comment: @Enigmativity sorry, but I'm still new with this, so I don't know how to start writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Substring of the Filename, parse it as Datetime and have to print it with the .ToString() function.

If you have the date value in a Datetime variable you can print it as you wish:

DTvariable.ToString("dd\MM\yyyy hh:mm")

Do you need further assistance to extract the datevalue into an Datetime variable?

Comment: Yes, I need. How do I write the code? Can you share with me how you would code it? I managed to do load local file then from the file, I will have an output of a new excel file which is the date and time that need to be in the output excel file.

Comment: If you want it as a Console-Program, there is no one line solution. You have to dig deeper into .Net to accomplish this, post some code and I will help you - but I won't do your job lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string fileName = "File_1_" + dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

You can use format date.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, i used the answer from steven above for this.
Please have a look at the code and you should see how regex are working...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var filename = "File_1_20170428101607";
  var date = ParseDateFromFilename(filename);
  if (date == null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Could not parse date");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Found date: " + date.ToString());
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Takes a filename and parses the timestamp out of it
/// If parsing is not possible it returns null
/// else the date
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static DateTime? ParseDateFromFilename(string filename)
{
  //regex is used to extract the 14 digit timestamp from filename
  var timestamp = Regex.Match(filename, @"\d{14}$");
  if (!timestamp.Success)
  {
    //if no match was found return null
    return null;
  }

  try
  {
    //try to parse the date with known timestamp and return
    return DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
  catch
  {
    //any error -> parsing was not possible -> return null
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I run the code but there's error. `var timestamp = Regex.Match(filename, @"\d{14}$"); ` stated that the name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context. Then, for this code  `return DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp.Value,  "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` is stated that the name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Yeah. As the Regex class is in another namespace you need to import that namespace. Add using System.Text.RegularExpressions; and for CultureInfo add using System.Globalization to your using directives.